# Socket IO 2.0 won't connect from VB.NET windows service

Tags: vb.net, socket.io

I am trying to use socket IO from a >NET windows server. The same code works perfectly from windows forms.

Declaration:

```
Public socketIO As Quobject.SocketIoClientDotNet.Client.Socket
```

Code:

```
 Try
        Dim O As New IO.Options
        O.AutoConnect = True
        O.IgnoreServerCertificateValidation = True
        socketIO = IO.Socket("http://XXXXXX:8000", O)
        'socket = IO.Socket(Socket_Server & ":" & Socket_Server_Port, O)
        socketIO.On(socketIO.EVENT_CONNECT, Sub()
                                                socketIO.Emit("unique", MemCPUID)
                                            End Sub)
        socketIO.On(socketIO.EVENT_RECONNECT, Sub(data)

                                              End Sub)
        socketIO.On(socketIO.EVENT_MESSAGE, Sub(data)

                                            End Sub)
        socketIO.On(socketIO.EVENT_ERROR, Sub(data)

                                          End Sub)

        socketIO.On(socketIO.EVENT_CONNECT_ERROR, Sub(data)

                                                  End Sub)
        socketIO.On("CON", Sub(data As String)
                               Sresp(data)
                           End Sub)
    Catch ex As exception
    End Try
```

The Catch dosn't get hit and scoketIO connected=False 
Also the events never fires.

The exact same code run from windows forms runs perfectly. Already tried to disable firewall.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with a wrong version DLL I was using. Everything is working fine now.